# Confuse between JSON array and JSON object

Tags: json

```
{

error: false

-booking: [2]

-0:  {

           booking_id: 32
           booking_user_id: 25
           booking_service_id: 1
           booking_date: "2015-10-01 12:16:48"
           booking_completion_date: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
           booking_location_latitude: 23432
           booking_location-longitude: 2134123
}

-1:  {
         booking_id: 59
         booking_user_id: 25
         booking_service_id: 2
         booking_date: "2015-10-03 15:31:51"
         booking_completion_date: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
         booking_location_latitude: 1
         booking_location-longitude: 1

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add more infos about it...
You have there an Array of Objects... so what do you need to do with those?

Comment: actually i want to display this JSON code in an android app.. so i dont know how to handle this codes...

Comment: Without a stacktrace or a logcat and your sourcecode it is impossible to help.

Comment: just remember curly braces '{' means jsonobject ... and square braces '[' means jsonarray

Answer (score 0):

JSON Object :

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins
>   with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is
>   followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by ,
>   (comma).

JSON Array :

> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [
>   (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated
>   by , (comma).

Answer (score 0):

Yo have an Array of Booking with 2 Objects inside: `booking: [2]`
the 1st Object is:

```
 { booking_id: 32
booking_user_id: 25

   booking_service_id: 1
   booking_date: "2015-10-01 12:16:48"
   booking_completion_date: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   booking_location_latitude: 23432
   booking_location-longitude: 2134123
}
```

and the 2nd is:

```
{booking_id: 59

 booking_user_id: 25
 booking_service_id: 2
 booking_date: "2015-10-03 15:31:51"
 booking_completion_date: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
 booking_location_latitude: 1
 booking_location-longitude: 1
}
```

now, the most useful way to handle those is to define a Json Parser or deserializer, with this Deserializer you can construct instances of a "Booking Class", the rest is up to you with a View Model Controller.

Now, lets assume you are using the Google Json API from [Gson Repo](https://github.com/google/gson)
If you have the json in a String Object:

```
String myJsonAsString = "[{'booking_id': 32, 'booking_date': \"2015-10-01 12:16:48\" },"
            + "{ 'booking_id': 59 , 'booking_date': \"2015-10-03 15:31:51\"}]";
```

then use the Gson Clases:

```
JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(myJsonAsString);
        JsonArray jsonArray = root.getAsJsonArray();
        JsonObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        String booking_date = jsonObject1.get("booking_date").toString();
        System.out.println("booking_date: " + booking_date);
```

and you will get in the console:

```
booking_date: "2015-10-01 12:16:48"
```

Try first with something trivial, is you are not familiar with Json: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Comment: Can you tell me how to parse these array of booking in android.. i want to store them in arrays..